# How to detect that it's Twitter requesting my page

Tags: php, redirect, twitter

According to Tweet Button documentation (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button/faq#count-api-increment) posted article must be accessible with HTTP response code 200, to allow Twitter counting your articles.

Current set up of our website is this:
1. article URL has following link: /post/:date/:title
2. link which is shared via Twitter is: /:date/:title (I don't know why - I didn't design it)
3. when someone is accessing the second link, backend code is performing 301 redirect to the first link

To fix Tweets counting I need to serve response code 200 with JS script code to perform redirect(e.g. window.location = '...'). But it will break 301 redirects for Google bot crawling the website, which is something we want to avoid (SEO reasons).

So the only solution I see is to leave 301 redirect, and serve different one only to Twitter, when it's trying to `curl` my website.

But how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I've just found a solution to my problem.

According to Twitter docs (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/getting-started#crawling) Twitter is using `Twitterbot` user agent, and basing on this I write following snippet of code:

```
if( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Twitterbot') !== false ) { // for twitter counting
    echo('<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "/post/:date/:title"</script>');
    die;
}
else {
    header('Location: /post/:date/:title', true, 301);
    die;
}
```

Hope it helps someone in the future.